# Using RegExp to Replace 'undefined' from data from API with a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm using an API to get book information: title and author, but realized that some authors data come back as 'undefined'. I thought of using RegExp to replace the undefined I get from the API to a string of 'N/A' but am stuck.

```
/* inside a function */
function someAsyncFunction() {

  /* fetching data happening here */

  const data = await res.json();

  const books = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
    let titles = data.items[i].title;
    let authors = data.items[i].author;

    if (typeof titles === 'undefined' || typeof authors === 'undefined') {

      // I would like to replace 'undefined' with a string of 'N/A'

    }

    books.push(`${data.items[i].title} by ${data.items[i].authors}`);
  }

  return books;
}
```

A sample output I get is: ["Cats by undefined"], and what I would like to get is: ["Cats by N/A"].

Comment: Do they come back undefined or as the string `'undefined'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't need a regex here, as `undefined` is a special type, not a string. You just need to overwrite the value with a default; you can use a common pattern of short-circuiting for that:

```
let titles = data.items[i].title || 'N/A';
let authors = data.items[i].author || 'N/A';
```

This works because the `||` ("or") operator will return the first non-falsy value in the list, or the last value if they're all falsy. Since undefined is falsy and non-empty strings are truthy, this will use the string if it exists or 'N/A' if it's undefined.

Comment: You explained it in more detail, you win.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an approach. It uses a default object to fill the gaps in the objects you get. The advantage is that you don't deal with the property names inside the consolidation part, thus it is easier to add properties. IMHO it is maintainable. However, lets no room for intrinsic logic when filling the gaps.

```js
const def = {author: 'N/A', title: 'N/A'} 
let data = [
  { author: 'A1', title: 'T1'},
  { author: 'A2'},
  { title: 'T2'}
]

data = data.map(x => Object.assign({},def , x))

console.log(data)
```

Comment: You don't need to nest your assigns; you can just do `Object.assign({}, def, x)`

Comment: To be honest, you shouldn't be using map like that, either. You should be doing `data = data.map(x => Object.assign({}, def, x))` -- the point of `map` is that it returns a new array with the entries mapped already, you shouldn't need to assign the mapping of each entry yourself. Or, if you prefer to do that, you should use forEach instead of map.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk True again. That was left from a previous alternative. Although it is not illegal, it breaks the functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

If `titles` is a string type and it has `"undefined"` string value, you can use `RegEx` as you want like:

```
...
titles = titles.replace(/undefined/g, "N/A");
...
```

But if `titles` is `undefined(no value)`, I suggest you to use like this:

```
titles = titles || 'N/A';
```

This will return `"N/A"` if `titles` is `undefined`/`null`/`""` or `0` (if `titles` is number type), otherwise it'll return `titles` itself.